# How to get Serial Number and IMEI Number in android 10 and above versions

Tags: android, flutter

I am want get Serial number and IMEI number in Android version 10 and above.
I have research and found out the solution for the Work profile application. but I am not sure that how to achieved that with the work profile. more over? I never work with Work profile so don't know how to build application with work profile either?
so anyone in the community can help me with that. It'll be really Appreciable.

Many Thanks

Comment: i tried many things and packages useless

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin `imei_plugin: ^1.2.0`

Get IMEI (International Mobile Device Identity) for Android devices less than android 10 with runtime permission for android greater than or equal to 10 returns a UUID and get unique identification on ios An alphanumeric string that uniquely identifies a device for the application provider.

```
import 'package:imei_plugin/imei_plugin.dart';


String imei = await ImeiPlugin.getImei();
List<String> multiImei = await ImeiPlugin.getImeiMulti(); //for double-triple SIM phones
String uuid = await ImeiPlugin.getId();


String platformImei = await ImeiPlugin
    .getImei( shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale: false );
```

Comment: I have already tried with this plugin does noe get success. Can you please help me on how to build work profile for the android application because that is the only way around.

Comment: Sorry bro, don't know